# Meaning of $f=me$ Factorization in Abelian Categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

> ***Propsition 1***, part 1 (Maclane, CWM p.199)
>
> Let $\mathsf A$ be an abelian category. Then every arrow has a factorization $f=me$, with
>   $m$ monic and $e$ epic; moreover, $$m=\ker (\text{coker}
>  f),\;\;\;\;e=\text{coker} (\ker f)$$

What is the intuitive meaning of this decomposition, in particular of the one consisting of the above $m,e$, and why is it significant?

Comment: Your question is too broad. This is just the usual image factorization. Please make the question more specific.

Comment: This theorem states, that in Abelian categories, image and coimage coincide, which is very useful.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I'm asking for the structural significance of this decomposition, why it's interesting, what does it mean intuitively etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest to understand with an example, so let $R$ be a ring and consider the category of left $R$-modules.  If $f\colon M \to N$ is a homomorphism then categorically it's kernel and cokernel are the homomorphisms
$$\mathrm{ker} \ f \to M \qquad \text{and} \qquad N \to N/\mathrm{im} \ f$$
where here $\mathrm{ker} \ f \subseteq M$ and $\mathrm{im} \ f \subseteq N$ take their non-categorical meanings as submodules (instead of their categorical meanings as maps).

Now the maps $m$ and $e$ are
$$m\colon\mathrm{im} \ f \to N \qquad \text{and} \qquad e\colon M \to M/\mathrm{ker} \ f.$$
The first isomorphism theorem gives $M/\mathrm{ker} \ f \simeq \mathrm{im} \ f$ and the composition
$$M \overset{e}{\rightarrow} M/\mathrm{ker} \ f \simeq \mathrm{im} \ f \overset{m}{\rightarrow} N$$
is in fact the map $f$.

As you see from the example, this is just factoring a map through it's image.

Comment: or by its kernel, and these two ways are isomorphic!